# iOS Local notification shows old application name

Tags: ios, push-notification, localnotification

We are updating application with new application name. When user updates app it changes the application name. We are setting some local notifications through application in earlier version. After update we are removing those notifications and registering some new notifications.But if application is updated and user gets the notifications in new version then it still shows the old application name in notification bar. Where as if fresh application is installed it shows new application name in notification. How can we show new application name in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I understanding your scenario, the thing which I got is that when user updating the App, there still old version local notification configure before.

I advise you to Cancel all local notifications immediately when your update the App with this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

And make sure **cancelAllLocalNotifications** call only once, you can do this by using `bool` with `NSUserDefault`.

And by doing this the local notification which were fire before with the old App name will be cancel and new local notification will configure with the new App name.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: If doing this, (and to make it easier to recreate them) you can always get any existing local notifications from ````NSArray *existingLocalNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];```` pull out the userInfo ````[existingLocalNotifications valueForKey:@"userInfo"];```` and then recreate them using these details

Comment: Yes your right ,by doing this we can cancel all local notifications and schedule the new one and hence issue will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

This will show if you use the same certificate for both the application. try to change the certificate your problem will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that there's not much you can do besides [filing a bug](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).